# How can we add Flurry to AdMobs or AdWhirl Mediation?

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl, flurry

How can we integrate Flurry to Admobs or AdWhirl Mediation ?? Is we cant Flurry using Webpage then, do we need to add it using Code ? I am working in Android, how can we do that?

Comment: Do you mean Flurry Analytics?

Comment: @jandjorgensen : No Flurry Ad

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "Custom Event" to try to integrate an unsupported ad network (since Flurry doesn't look like they have an out of box adapter you can use with AdWhirl).

Take a look at how to create Custom Event [here](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/wiki/CustomEvents).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't.

If the mediator is not offering an option to integrate a specific Ad netwrok, there's really no way to "extend" their code and include an additional Ad network.

One tactic we use and that you might want to take a look at, is just sending traffic to the additional Ad network (in this case Flurry), when your mediator can't fill an Ad request.